# Could this be the reason my laptop(Lenovo Y510)'s GPU is under clocked to 400 (from 1150) after being hit hard?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power, gpu

After my laptop got hit pretty heavily on the 'G' key, the GPU's core clock has been reduced from 980 (1150 on boost). But using NvidiaInspector for setting the GPU clock directly, i have confirmed that the clock can go up to 810 MHz, Although the thermostat reports the heat to be around 95 when its only at 60 (assessing from experience) and so, the GPU clock throttles down to 400 again, and also, the display is dimmer on maximum brightness when unplugged, compared to when plugged on maximum brightness.

This has led me to think there is a problem with power distribution, not on AC receiver(!), but something on the motherboard maybe, that distributes power between components.

Now I have two questions. 1, is my assumption correct, and if yes, what is the problematic part? 2, what could be the reason of errors in thermostat reports?

Comment: The temperature being read by the software is likely to be a thermal diode in the GPU core and should be correct. More likely is that the drop or hit dislodged the heatsink and you are not getting good thermal contact between the chip and heatsink (hence you seeing 60 while the core is higher). Replace the thermal pads or putty and make sure the heatsinks are making good contact and the fans are running well.

Comment: @Mokubai you got me wrong. I said that the software shows a higher temp than what the actual temp is. The amount of chassis hotness proves it. Plus, the temp shown by the software is really unstable. The moment you close a game, the temp drops from ~95 to ~60 in under a second, which this did not use to happen. And i'm pretty sure that the wrong report of the temp is the reason the gpu throttles down, when i directy oc it to a higher number (usually above 650).

Comment: No, I understood you perfectly and I stand by what I said. I trust the GPU reported temperature and what you've said just reinforces that for me. It's not making good thermal contact with it's heatsink so whatever heat it generates is going into its small case and it is throttling. Once you stop using it then the temperature will drop quickly because it isnt being kept high due to a large hot thermal mass around it. It is possible that other factors are at play, but after a large shock you check for mechanical faults like heatsinks and thermal joints first.

Comment: Make of my advice what you will, but changing thermal materials is the easiest thing that you as a user can do. How are you checking the temperature? Do you have a thermocouple stuck to the GPU **chip** (accurate), on the heatsink (inaccurate), or are you using a laser thermometer (nearly useless)?

Comment: @Mokubai I think i understand what you're saying. I will try changing thermal materials. And no, im not using any devices to measure the temp. I read it from oc softwares and check how hot the metal around the air vent has become. Thanks.